# ¿Como obtener los datos de un archivo XML?

Tags: c#, xml, consola

Buen día.

Estoy realizando una aplicación en C#, en ella se lee u archivo de texto y genera un factura, me encuentro con un detalle al querer un archivo de configuración XML.
Requiero leer los nodos de este archivos y pasarlos esos a datos para realizar varias acciones.
Anexo el código XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Config>
  <Timbrar Timbrado="0"></Timbrar>
  <Empresas RFC="AAA010101AAA" RutaEmpresa="C:\Compac\Empresas\adEmpresa_Demo">
    <Conceptos Serie="NX001" Folio="0" Password="12345678a" > </Conceptos>
    <Conceptos Serie="MXN" Folio="0" Password="12345678a"></Conceptos>
  </Empresas>
  <Empresas RFC="AAA010101AAE" RutaEmpresa="C:\Compac\Empresas\adEmpresa_Demo2021">
    <Conceptos Serie="NX001" Folio="0" Password="12345678a"></Conceptos>
    <Conceptos Serie="MXN01" Folio="0" Password="12345678a"></Conceptos>
  </Empresas>
</Config>
```

De este archivo intento tomar los datos de Empresas y Conceptos (todos los nodos).
He intentado de la siguiente manera pero el se repite la función varias veces y no logro hacer que solo muestre los datos correctos.

```
        public static void AbreEmpresa()
        {
            string txtRFC = "AAA010101AAA"; //Este dato lo tomara del archivo txt
            string codConep = "MX001";//Este dato lo tomara del archivo txt

            XmlDocument xmlRuta = new XmlDocument();
            xmlRuta.Load("C:\\Users\\Contpaqi\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Proyects\\Producotos y Clientes\\Producotos y Clientes\\Config.xml");

            XmlNodeList nodeEmpresa = xmlRuta.GetElementsByTagName("Empresas");
            XmlNodeList nodeConceptos = xmlRuta.GetElementsByTagName("Conceptos");

            for (int c = 0; c < nodeConceptos.Count; c++)
            {
                string xSerie = nodeConceptos[c].Attributes["Serie"].Value;
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeEmpresa.Count; i++)
                {
                    string xRFC = nodeEmpresa[i].Attributes["RFC"].Value;
                    string xEmpresa = nodeEmpresa[i].Attributes["RutaEmpresa"].Value;
                    
                    if (txtRFC == xRFC)
                    {
                        if (codConep == xSerie)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(xEmpresa);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   
        }
```

En esta prueba me repite 6 veces la ruta de la empresa, cuando solo debería hacerlo 4 veces.
Cualquier ayuda, sugerencia para mejorar es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

¿Te puede funcionar algo como esto?

```
static XmlNode SearchNodes()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlRuta = new XmlDocument();
        xmlRuta.Load("C:\\Users\\Contpaqi\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Proyects\\Producotos y Clientes\\Producotos y Clientes\\Config.xml");
        
        XmlNode RFC = xmlRuta.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode Ruta = xmlRuta.DocumentElement;

        XmlNodeList xRFC = xmlRuta.SelectNodes("//Empresas/@RFC");
        foreach (XmlNode rfc in xRFC) 
        {
            RFC = rfc;
            Console.WriteLine(RFC.Value);
        }

        XmlNodeList xRutaEmpresa = xmlRuta.SelectNodes("//Empresas/@RutaEmpresa");
        foreach (XmlNode ruta in xRutaEmpresa)
        {
            Ruta = ruta;
            Console.WriteLine(Ruta.Value);
        }
         
        return Ruta;
    }
```

En consola el resultado es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola María, agradezco tu respuesta, sin embargo no me seria útil, ya que esos datos los requiero ocupar en otro parte del código y unicamente existen dentro de los foreach.

Comment: Ow, siendo así. Podrías crear un método del tipo de dato que deseas extraer, para que hagas **return** y te devuelva un valor en específico aún estando en un foreach.

Edité el código que te comparto, con el método así puedes mandarlo llamar en otro, ¿aun así no es factible?

Comment: Hola María, aun no me funciona, lo que pasa es que tomo datos de un archivo txt, de ahí los comparo con el XML y dos de esos datos coinciden deben abrir la empresa correspondiente. El detalle es que como existen en el XML los Conceptos y en el atributo de ese nodo existe un dato igual, es ahí cuando duplica la apertura de la empresa.

Comment: Formule una nueva pregunta esperando se entienda mejor en ella lo que requiero: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/442425/comparar-datos-de-un-archivo-txt-con-un-xml-en-c